# incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and Windows-1251

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8

I am parsing a russian website with nokogiri.

This is my controller

```
class ParserController < ApplicationController
  require 'open-uri'

  require 'nokogiri'


  def test
     source = 'http://www.rp.ru/shop/?set_filter=Y&query=&level1=%CE%C1%CE%D0%D3%C4%CE%C2%C0%CD%C8%C5+%C4%CB%DF+%CC%C0%C3%C0%C7%C8%CD%C0&level2=%D5%CE%CB%CE%C4%C8%CB%DC%CD%CE%C5+%CE%C1%CE%D0%D3%C4%CE%C2%C0%CD%C8%C5&level3=%CB%C0%D0%DC+%CC%CE%D0%CE%C7%C8%CB%DC%CD%DB%C9%2C+%D5%CE%CB%CE%C4%C8%CB%DC%CD%DB%C9&tid=4_2225606&q=&manufacturer=0&type=0&count=100&XML_ID=&section=0&sort=0&show_type=1'

     page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(source))
     @titles = []
     page.css('.salenamebrand').each do |t|
     @titles << t
  end
end
```

And this is my view

```
<% @titles.each do |t| %>
<%=t%>

<%end%>
```

And I get this error:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError in Parser#test

incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and Windows-1251
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like i just needed to write something like this:      `@titles << t.text` and it works now!